# SwfitUI elements does not changing after @State is changed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm pretty new when it comes to SwiftUI. What I'm trying to build is onboarding screens. One of these screens that I currently working on is when I need to request from a user a bunch of privacy information like access to the camera, Apple Photo Library, microphone, location, and notifications.
[here's the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r78JD.png) and
[here's privacy request from Info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd8C8.png)

Now I start running the app and clicking on the blue Allow button to start requesting the user's data.
[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iILxe.png)

And when it comes to requesting location and notification data, the problems start to occur. First [here's location permission pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RaKD.jpg) I made a choice and the UI element [checkmark] didn't show up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksdbX.png) like to indicate the user's choice and that's the first problem that I trying to fix. But when I click again on the blue Allow button now is showing at the same time two checkmarks (for location and notifications) and that's the second problem [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYmSZ.png). Like the same problem with notifications checkmark that I need to click again on the blue Allow button.

Please help to solve these problems because I tried everything I could. Additionally here's all the code for doing that:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Photos
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {

@AppStorage("onBoardingViewed") var hasOnboarded = false
private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

// MARK: - UI States

@State private var isAllowedCamera = false
@State private var isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
@State private var isAllowedMicrophone = false
@State private var isAllowedLocation = false
@State private var isAllowedNotification = false

@State private var isHiddenCam = true
@State private var isHiddenPL = true
@State private var isHiddenMic = true
@State private var isHiddenLoc = true
@State private var isHiddenNot = true

@State private var isFinished = false

// MARK: - UI

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 60) {
        
        Text("Allow Access")
            .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: isAllowedCamera ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedCamera ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenCam ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenPL ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedMicrophone ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedMicrophone ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenMic ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedLocation ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedLocation ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenLoc ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedNotification ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedNotification ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenLoc ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                Text("Camera permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Photos permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Microphone permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Location permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Notification permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: - Action
        
        Button {
            
            reqestCamera { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedCamera = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedCamera = false
                }
                isHiddenCam = false
            }
            
            reqestPhotoLibrary { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedPhotoLibrary = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
                }
                isHiddenPL = false
            }
            
            reqestMicrophone { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedMicrophone = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedMicrophone = false
                }
                isHiddenMic = false
                
                reqestLocation { (success) in

                    if success == true {
                        isAllowedLocation = true
                        print("Location ON")
                    } else {
                        isAllowedLocation = false
                        print("Location OFF")
                    }

                    isHiddenLoc = false

                    reqestNotifications { (success) in
                        if success == true {
                            isAllowedNotification = true
                        } else {
                            isAllowedNotification = false
                        }

                        isHiddenNot = false
                        isFinished = true
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if isFinished == true {
                withAnimation {
                    hasOnboarded = true
                }
            }
            
        } label: {
            Text(isFinished ? "START" : "ALLOW")
                .font(.custom("SF-Compact-Rounded-Medium", size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Request access methods

private func reqestCamera(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: completion)
}

private func reqestPhotoLibrary(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .addOnly) { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            completion(true)
        case .limited:
            completion(true)
        case .notDetermined:
            completion(false)
        case .restricted:
            completion(false)
        case .denied:
            completion(false)
        @unknown default:
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

private func reqestMicrophone(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio, completionHandler: completion)
}

private func reqestLocation(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let status = locationManager.authorizationStatus
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            print("autorized--------")
            completion(true)
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways {
            completion(true)
        } else if status == .denied {
            completion(false)
            print("denied--------")
        } else if status == .restricted {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

private func reqestNotifications(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                completion(true)
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Updated code

Now it has onboarding screens and AllowAccsesView. I hope you will see the problem more clearly now. For example when the user will stop in the middle of the privacy request progress or will update the app then he will see a checkmark only for location permission and at the first page will ask permission for notification screen right away and the button is not changing to "start" label

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Photos
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // MARK: - UI
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Color.red
            Color.yellow
            AllowAccsesView()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
    
    // MARK: - Request access methods
    
    private func reqestCamera(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: completion)
    }
    
    private func reqestPhotoLibrary(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .addOnly) { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                completion(true)
            case .limited:
                completion(true)
            case .notDetermined:
                completion(false)
            case .restricted:
                completion(false)
            case .denied:
                completion(false)
            @unknown default:
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func reqestMicrophone(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct AllowAccsesView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("onBoardingViewed") var hasOnboarded = false
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @ObservedObject var locManager = LocationManager()
    @ObservedObject var notificationManager = NotificationManager()
    
    // MARK: - UI States
    
    @State private var isAllowedCamera = false
    @State private var isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
    @State private var isAllowedMicrophone = false
    @State private var isAllowedLocation = false
    @State private var isAllowedNotification = false
    
    @State private var isHiddenCam = true
    @State private var isHiddenPL = true
    @State private var isHiddenMic = true
    @State private var isHiddenLoc = true
    @State private var isHiddenNot = true
    
    @State private var isFinished = false
    
    // MARK: - UI
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 60) {
            
            Text("Allow Access")
                .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    Image(systemName: isAllowedCamera ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(isAllowedCamera ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .scaleEffect(isHiddenCam ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(.spring())
                    
                    Image(systemName: isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .scaleEffect(isHiddenPL ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(.spring())
                    
                    Image(systemName: isAllowedMicrophone ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(isAllowedMicrophone ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .scaleEffect(isHiddenMic ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(.spring())
                    
                    Image(systemName: (locManager.authorisationStatus.rawValue == 4) ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor((locManager.authorisationStatus.rawValue == 4) ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .scaleEffect((locManager.authorisationStatus.rawValue != 4) ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(.spring())
                    
                    Image(systemName: notificationManager.allowedNotifications ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(notificationManager.allowedNotifications ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .scaleEffect(notificationManager.allowedNotifications ? 1 : 0)
                        .animation(.spring())
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Camera permission")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    Text("Photos permission")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    Text("Microphone permission")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    Text("Location permission")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    Text("Notification permission")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                }
            }
            
            // MARK: - Action
            
            Button {
                
                reqestCamera { (success) in
                    if success {
                        isAllowedCamera = true
                    } else {
                        isAllowedCamera = false
                    }
                    isHiddenCam = false
                }
                
                reqestPhotoLibrary { (success) in
                    if success {
                        isAllowedPhotoLibrary = true
                    } else {
                        isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
                    }
                    isHiddenPL = false
                }
                
                reqestMicrophone { (success) in
                    if success {
                        isAllowedMicrophone = true
                    } else {
                        isAllowedMicrophone = false
                    }
                    isHiddenMic = false
                    
                    self.locManager.notificationManager = notificationManager
                    self.locManager.request()
                    
                }
                
                if notificationManager.showResult {
                    withAnimation {
                        hasOnboarded = true
                    }
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text(locManager.notificationManager.showResult ? "START" : "ALLOW")
                    .font(.custom("SF-Compact-Rounded-Medium", size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Request access methods
    
    private func reqestCamera(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: completion)
    }
    
    private func reqestPhotoLibrary(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .addOnly) { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                completion(true)
            case .limited:
                completion(true)
            case .notDetermined:
                completion(false)
            case .restricted:
                completion(false)
            case .denied:
                completion(false)
            @unknown default:
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func reqestMicrophone(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var authorisationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
            if newValue == .authorizedWhenInUse {
                notificationManager.requestPush()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var notificationManager = NotificationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    public func request() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.authorisationStatus = status
    }
}

class NotificationManager : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allowedNotifications = false
    @Published var showResult = false

    func requestPush() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.allowedNotifications = true
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showResult = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This happens due to the fact that Location and Notification run in DispatchQueue

Comment: ok thanks, Davidev, but could you please help me how to make work with that DispatchQueue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I have created two new Manager classes which deals with the Location and Notification Request.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@AppStorage("onBoardingViewed") var hasOnboarded = false
private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
@ObservedObject var locManager = LocationManager()
@ObservedObject var notificationManager = NotificationManager()

// MARK: - UI States

@State private var isAllowedCamera = false
@State private var isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
@State private var isAllowedMicrophone = false
@State private var isAllowedLocation = false
@State private var isAllowedNotification = false

@State private var isHiddenCam = true
@State private var isHiddenPL = true
@State private var isHiddenMic = true
@State private var isHiddenLoc = true
@State private var isHiddenNot = true

@State private var isFinished = false

// MARK: - UI

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 60) {
        
        Text("Allow Access")
            .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: isAllowedCamera ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedCamera ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenCam ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedPhotoLibrary ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenPL ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: isAllowedMicrophone ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(isAllowedMicrophone ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(isHiddenMic ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: (locManager.authorisationStatus.rawValue == 4) ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor((locManager.authorisationStatus.rawValue == 4) ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(!locManager.showResult ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
                
                Image(systemName: notificationManager.allowedNotifications ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(notificationManager.allowedNotifications ? Color.green : Color.red)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .scaleEffect(!notificationManager.showResult ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                Text("Camera permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Photos permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Microphone permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Location permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text("Notification permission")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: - Action
        
        Button {
            
            reqestCamera { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedCamera = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedCamera = false
                }
                isHiddenCam = false
            }
            
            reqestPhotoLibrary { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedPhotoLibrary = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedPhotoLibrary = false
                }
                isHiddenPL = false
            }
            
            reqestMicrophone { (success) in
                if success {
                    isAllowedMicrophone = true
                } else {
                    isAllowedMicrophone = false
                }
                isHiddenMic = false
                

                self.locManager.notificationManager = notificationManager
                self.locManager.request()

            }
            
            if isFinished == true {
                withAnimation {
                    hasOnboarded = true
                }
            }
            
        } label: {
            Text(isFinished ? "START" : "ALLOW")
                .font(.custom("SF-Compact-Rounded-Medium", size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the following Location Manager classes:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var authorisationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    var showResult = false {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
            notificationManager.requestPush()
        }
    }
    
    var notificationManager = NotificationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    public func request() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.authorisationStatus = status
        
        if (status != .notDetermined) {
            self.showResult = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

And the following Notification Manager:

```
class NotificationManager : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allowedNotifications = false
    @Published var showResult = false

    func requestPush() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.allowedNotifications = true
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showResult = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I makes use of `ObservedObject`. Location and Notification Manager acts as `ObservableObject`. When the Status updates, the icon of your view updates accordingly. The problem is the sequence, calling one after another. That's why it is necessary to pass the NotificationManager to the LocationManager. The Location Manager will call the Notification when it is finished.

And the screen looks amazing by the way. Really cool idea with that icons! Очень хорошо

Edit:

Here is a update for loading the initial state of push notifications.

Inside NotificationManager add following `init()` method

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
        {
            self.allowedNotifications = true
            self.showResult = true
        }
        else if (settings.authorizationStatus == .denied)
        {
            self.allowedNotifications = false
            self.showResult = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that works cool, thanks for that Davidev, really appreciate it) but it's only work when user will allow access to location and notification, if user will don't allow then it simply will not show up the chosen result of the request

Comment: and really thank you for checking out my solution with icons and the screen, I glad you like it,  Дякую 

Comment: Ласкаво просимо. Thanks for the response. I will check it again and edit/ get back to you if I found a solution.

Comment: That's awesome  Thanks a lot Davidev  definitely need to dive more into and be familiar with your solution. Now I trying to change isFinished state when all requests all done to change from blue Allow button to Start button

Comment: Hi David, I found an interesting bug and don't know how to fix it. The problem is when I move to Notification permission then disallow it then the image for checkmark didn't appear and for example, the user will close the app and then open it again it only showing a checkmark for location. Please help)

Comment: Privet) I checked out the last example from above. I could recreate the issue. I updated the code above. Just add that init() method to NotificationManager.

Comment: Privet) I really appreciate your help but it still has the same issue, maybe I didn't explain it more clearly, sorry about that. So I have like onboarding screen with several pages and the last one is related to this view with Privacy requests.

Comment: Like the previous code without init in NotificationManager was working great except the fact when for example the user in the middle of requests getting a cal or just switching to another app and returning back to the app he see a checkmark on location already and for example this is happening when installing another build without deleting the previous one and right away

Comment: when the user open the app at first onboarding page witch is not related to privacy requests it's requesting notification right away and that's a little bit strange and I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Mh not sure if I understand everything correctly. If you close the app and then reopen, what do you expect to see? If he previous allowed location, the checkmark should be there right?

Comment: right, but it's only showing a checkmark for location, and also weird to see notification request pop up on the first page of the onboarding screen because this view with users requests is the lalt one, this is happening when updating the app with a new build of the app

Comment: I updated the code above) please, have a glance)

Comment: Okay, I have a solution for location. Can we write somewhere else then its easier to share code than changing that question constantly? Discord Or Stackoverflow chat?

Comment: sure) just one sec